# Difference between Batch Normalization and Self Normalized Neural Network with SELU

Tags: neural-network, batch-normalization

I would like to know the difference between batch normalization and self normalized neural network. In other words, would SELU (Scaled Exponential Linear Unit) replace batch normalization and how?

Moreover, I after looking into the values of the SELU activations, they were in the range: `[-1, 1]`. While this is not the case with batch normalization. Instead, the values after the `BN` layer (before the relu activation), took the values of `[-a, a]` Approximately, and not `[-1, 1]`.

Here is how I printed the values after the SELU activation and after batch norm layer:

```
batch_norm_layer = tf.Print(batch_norm_layer,
                           data=[tf.reduce_max(batch_norm_layer), tf.reduce_min(batch_norm_layer)],
                           message = name_scope + ' min and max')
```

And similar code for the SELU activations...

Batch norm layer is defined as follows:

```
def batch_norm(x, n_out, phase_train, in_conv_layer = True):

    with tf.variable_scope('bn'):
        beta = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=n_out),
                                     name='beta', trainable=True)
        gamma = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=n_out),
                                      name='gamma', trainable=True)
        if in_conv_layer:
            batch_mean, batch_var = tf.nn.moments(x, [0, 1, 2], name='moments')
        else:
            batch_mean, batch_var = tf.nn.moments(x, [0, 1], name='moments')

        ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(decay=0.9999)

        def mean_var_with_update():
            ema_apply_op = ema.apply([batch_mean, batch_var])
            with tf.control_dependencies([ema_apply_op]):
                return tf.identity(batch_mean), tf.identity(batch_var)

        mean, var = tf.cond(phase_train,
                            mean_var_with_update,
                            lambda: (ema.average(batch_mean), ema.average(batch_var)))
        normed = tf.nn.batch_normalization(x, mean, var, beta, gamma, 1e-3)
    return normed
```

Therefore, since batch norm outputs higher values, the loss increases dramatically, and thus I got nans.

In addition, I tried reducing the learning rate with batch norm, but, that didn't help as well. So how to fix this problem???

Here is the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2

batch_size = 32
num_epoch = 102
latent_dim = 100

def weight_variable(kernal_shape):
    weights = tf.get_variable(name='weights', shape=kernal_shape, dtype=tf.float32, trainable=True,
                        initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02))
    return weights

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.0, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def batch_norm(x, n_out, phase_train, convolutional = True):
    with tf.variable_scope('bn'):
        exp_moving_avg = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(decay=0.9999)

        beta = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=n_out),
                                     name='beta', trainable=True)
        gamma = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=n_out),
                                      name='gamma', trainable=True)
        if convolutional:
            batch_mean, batch_var = tf.nn.moments(x, [0, 1, 2], name='moments')

        else:
            batch_mean, batch_var = tf.nn.moments(x, [0], name='moments')

        update_moving_averages = exp_moving_avg.apply([batch_mean, batch_var])

        m = tf.cond(phase_train, lambda: exp_moving_avg.average(batch_mean), lambda: batch_mean)
        v = tf.cond(phase_train, lambda: exp_moving_avg.average(batch_var), lambda: batch_var)

        normed = tf.nn.batch_normalization(x, m, v, beta, gamma, 1e-3)
        normed = tf.Print(normed, data=[tf.shape(normed)], message='size of normed?')
    return normed, update_moving_averages   # Note that we should run the update_moving_averages with sess.run...

def conv_layer(x, w_shape, b_shape, padding='SAME'):
    W = weight_variable(w_shape)
    tf.summary.histogram("weights", W)

    b = bias_variable(b_shape)
    tf.summary.histogram("biases", b)

    # Note that I used a stride of 2 on purpose in order not to use max pool layer.
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding=padding) + b
    conv_batch_norm, update_moving_averages = batch_norm(conv, b_shape, phase_train=tf.cast(True, tf.bool))
    name_scope = tf.get_variable_scope().name

    conv_batch_norm = tf.Print(conv_batch_norm,
                               data=[tf.reduce_max(conv_batch_norm), tf.reduce_min(conv_batch_norm)],
                               message = name_scope + ' min and max')

    activations = tf.nn.relu(conv_batch_norm)
    tf.summary.histogram("activations", activations)

    return activations, update_moving_averages

def deconv_layer(x, w_shape, b_shape, padding="SAME", activation='selu'):
    W = weight_variable(w_shape)
    tf.summary.histogram("weights", W)

    b = bias_variable(b_shape)
    tf.summary.histogram('biases', b)

    x_shape = tf.shape(x)

    out_shape = tf.stack([x_shape[0], x_shape[1] * 2, x_shape[2] * 2, w_shape[2]])
    if activation == 'selu':
        conv_trans = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(x, W, out_shape, [1, 2, 2, 1], padding=padding) + b
        conv_trans_batch_norm, update_moving_averages = \
            batch_norm(conv_trans, b_shape, phase_train=tf.cast(True, tf.bool))
        transposed_activations = tf.nn.relu(conv_trans_batch_norm)

    else:
        conv_trans = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(x, W, out_shape, [1, 2, 2, 1], padding=padding) + b
        conv_trans_batch_norm, update_moving_averages = \
            batch_norm(conv_trans, b_shape, phase_train=tf.cast(True, tf.bool))
        transposed_activations = tf.nn.sigmoid(conv_trans_batch_norm)

    tf.summary.histogram("transpose_activation", transposed_activations)
    return transposed_activations, update_moving_averages

tfrecords_filename_seq = ["C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/AffectiveComputing/P16_db.tfrecords"]
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(tfrecords_filename_seq, num_epochs=num_epoch, shuffle=False, name='queue')
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()

_, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
features = tf.parse_single_example(
    serialized_example,
    # Defaults are not specified since both keys are required.
    features={
        'height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'annotation_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
    })

# This is how we create one example, that is, extract one example from the database.
image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
# The height and the weights are used to
height = tf.cast(features['height'], tf.int32)
width = tf.cast(features['width'], tf.int32)

# The image is reshaped since when stored as a binary format, it is flattened. Therefore, we need the
# height and the weight to restore the original image back.
image = tf.reshape(image, [height, width, 3])

annotation = tf.cast(features['annotation_raw'], tf.string)

min_after_dequeue = 100
num_threads = 1
capacity = min_after_dequeue + num_threads * batch_size
label_batch, images_batch = tf.train.batch([annotation, image],
                                           shapes=[[], [112, 112, 3]],
                                           batch_size=batch_size,
                                           capacity=capacity,
                                           num_threads=num_threads)

label_batch_splitted = tf.string_split(label_batch, delimiter=',')
label_batch_values = tf.reshape(label_batch_splitted.values, [batch_size, -1])
label_batch_numbers = tf.string_to_number(label_batch_values, out_type=tf.float32)
confidences = tf.slice(label_batch_numbers, begin=[0, 2], size=[-1, 1])

images_batch = tf.cast([images_batch], tf.float32)[0]  # Note that casting the image will increases its rank.

with tf.name_scope('image_normal'):
    images_batch = tf.map_fn(lambda img: tf.image.per_image_standardization(img), images_batch)
    #images_batch = tf.Print(images_batch, data=[tf.reduce_max(images_batch), tf.reduce_min(images_batch)],
    #                        message='min and max in images_batch')
with tf.variable_scope('conv1'):
    conv1, uma_conv1 = conv_layer(images_batch, [4, 4, 3, 32], [32])      # image size: [56, 56]
with tf.variable_scope('conv2'):
    conv2, uma_conv2 = conv_layer(conv1, [4, 4, 32, 64], [64])     # image size: [28, 28]
with tf.variable_scope('conv3'):
    conv3, uma_conv3 = conv_layer(conv2, [4, 4, 64, 128], [128])   # image size: [14, 14]
with tf.variable_scope('conv4'):
    conv4, uma_conv4 = conv_layer(conv3, [4, 4, 128, 256], [256])  # image size: [7, 7]
    conv4_reshaped = tf.reshape(conv4, [-1, 7 * 7 * 256], name='conv4_reshaped')

w_c_mu = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([7 * 7 * 256, latent_dim], stddev=0.1), name='weight_fc_mu')
b_c_mu = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[latent_dim]), name='biases_fc_mu')
w_c_sig = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([7 * 7 * 256, latent_dim], stddev=0.1), name='weight_fc_sig')
b_c_sig = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[latent_dim]), name='biases_fc_sig')
epsilon = tf.random_normal([1, latent_dim])

tf.summary.histogram('weights_c_mu', w_c_mu)
tf.summary.histogram('biases_c_mu', b_c_mu)
tf.summary.histogram('weights_c_sig', w_c_sig)
tf.summary.histogram('biases_c_sig', b_c_sig)

with tf.variable_scope('mu'):
    mu = tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(conv4_reshaped, w_c_mu), b_c_mu)
    tf.summary.histogram('mu', mu)

with tf.variable_scope('stddev'):
    stddev = tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(conv4_reshaped, w_c_sig), b_c_sig)
    tf.summary.histogram('stddev', stddev)

with tf.variable_scope('z'):
    latent_var = mu + tf.multiply(tf.sqrt(tf.exp(stddev)), epsilon)
    tf.summary.histogram('features_sig', stddev)

w_dc = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([latent_dim, 7 * 7 * 256], stddev=0.1), name='weights_dc')
b_dc = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[7 * 7 * 256]), name='biases_dc')
tf.summary.histogram('weights_dc', w_dc)
tf.summary.histogram('biases_dc', b_dc)

with tf.variable_scope('deconv4'):
    deconv4 = tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(latent_var, w_dc), b_dc)
    deconv4_batch_norm, uma_deconv4 = \
        batch_norm(deconv4, [7 * 7 * 256], phase_train=tf.cast(True, tf.bool), convolutional=False)

    deconv4 = tf.nn.relu(deconv4_batch_norm)
    deconv4_reshaped = tf.reshape(deconv4, [-1, 7, 7, 256], name='deconv4_reshaped')

with tf.variable_scope('deconv3'):
    deconv3, uma_deconv3 = deconv_layer(deconv4_reshaped, [3, 3, 128, 256], [128], activation='selu')
with tf.variable_scope('deconv2'):
    deconv2, uma_deconv2 = deconv_layer(deconv3, [3, 3, 64, 128], [64], activation='selu')
with tf.variable_scope('deconv1'):
    deconv1, uma_deconv1 = deconv_layer(deconv2, [3, 3, 32, 64], [32], activation='selu')
with tf.variable_scope('deconv_image'):
    deconv_image_batch, uma_deconv = deconv_layer(deconv1, [3, 3, 3, 32], [3], activation='sigmoid')

# loss function.
with tf.name_scope('loss_likelihood'):
    # temp1 shape: [32, 112, 112, 3]

    temp1 = images_batch * tf.log(deconv_image_batch + 1e-9) + (1 - images_batch) * tf.log(1 - deconv_image_batch + 1e-9)

    #temp1 = temp1 * confidences. This will give an error. Therefore, we should expand the dimension of confidence tensor
    confidences_ = tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(confidences, axis=1), axis=1) # shape: [32, 1, 1, 1].
    temp1 = temp1 * confidences_
    log_likelihood = -tf.reduce_sum(temp1, reduction_indices=[1, 2, 3])
    log_likelihood_total = tf.reduce_sum(log_likelihood)
    #l2_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(tf.subtract(images_batch, deconv_image_batch)))

with tf.name_scope('loss_KL'):
    # temp2 shape: [32, 200]
    temp2 = 1 + tf.log(tf.square(stddev + 1e-9)) - tf.square(mu) - tf.square(stddev)
    temp3 = temp2 * confidences     # confidences shape is [32, 1]
    KL_term = - 0.5 * tf.reduce_sum(temp3, reduction_indices=1)
    KL_term_total = tf.reduce_sum(KL_term)

with tf.name_scope('total_loss'):
    variational_lower_bound = tf.reduce_mean(log_likelihood + KL_term)
    tf.summary.scalar('loss', variational_lower_bound)
with tf.name_scope('optimizer'):
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.00001).minimize(variational_lower_bound)

init_op = tf.group(tf.local_variables_initializer(),
                   tf.global_variables_initializer())

saver = tf.train.Saver()

model_path = 'C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/VariationalAutoEncoder/' \
             'VariationalAutoEncoderFaces/tensorboard_logs/Graph_model/ckpt'

# Here is the session...
with tf.Session() as sess:

    train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/VariationalAutoEncoder/'
                                         'VariationalAutoEncoderFaces/tensorboard_logs/Event_files', sess.graph)

    merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

    # Note that init_op should start before the Coordinator and the thread otherwise, this will throw an error.
    sess.run(init_op)

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    step = 0

    to_run_list = [uma_conv1, uma_conv2, uma_conv3, uma_conv4, uma_deconv1, uma_deconv2, uma_deconv3,
                   uma_deconv4, uma_deconv, optimizer, variational_lower_bound, merged,
                   deconv_image_batch, image]

    # Note that the last name "Graph_model" is the name of the saved checkpoints file => the ckpt is saved
    # under tensorboard_logs.
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(
        os.path.dirname(model_path))
    if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
        saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        print('checkpoints are saved!!!')
    else:
        print('No stored checkpoints')
    epoch = 0
    while not coord.should_stop():

        _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, loss, summary, reconstructed_image, original_image = \
            sess.run(to_run_list)

        print('total loss:', loss)

        original_image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(original_image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        reconstructed_image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(reconstructed_image[0]), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        cv2.imshow('original_image', original_image)
        cv2.imshow('reconstructed_image', reconstructed_image)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        if step % 234 == 0:
            epoch += 1
            print('epoch:', epoch)
            if epoch == num_epoch - 2:
                coord.request_stop()

        if step % 100 == 0:
            train_writer.add_summary(summary, step)
            #print('total loss:', loss)
            #print('log_likelihood_', log_likelihood_)
            #print('KL_term', KL_term_)
        step += 1

    save_path = saver.save(sess, model_path)
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
    train_writer.close()
```

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: This is a fairly broad question. Could you help me scope what kind of answer you're looking for? SELU can be used in place of any of the other nonlinear activation functions and doesn't require other changes. Batch norm is more complicated than that

Comment: I mean, does SELU solves the internal convariate shift problem? If yes, than can we replace the batch_norm layer + relu with the SELU activation function? I would love to have an intuition about how the output activations would differ between the 2 configurations. Thank you @Ryan Stout

Comment: SELU is capable of keeping the mean and variance of activation (in the given domain) over layers. But it does not guarantee the activated layers are still normally distributed. Before applying SELU, the features should be normalized.

Comment: @MaosiChen, I like that, maybe your right. Can you provide me with some references for that?

Comment: @MaosiChen I have also found that Batch Normalization before SELU significantly outperforms SELU used  without Batch Norm. I haven't seen references with similar results, though.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some sample codes to show the trend of means and variances over 3 SELU layers. The numbers of nodes on the layers (including the input layer) are [15, 30, 30, 8]

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os

#-----------------------------------------------#
# https://github.com/bioinf-jku/SNNs/blob/master/selu.py
# The SELU activation function
def selu(x):
    with ops.name_scope('elu') as scope:
        alpha = 1.6732632423543772848170429916717
        scale = 1.0507009873554804934193349852946
        return scale*tf.where(x>=0.0, x, alpha*tf.nn.elu(x))

#-----------------------------------------------#
# https://github.com/bioinf-jku/SNNs/blob/master/selu.py
# alpha-dropout
def dropout_selu(x, rate, alpha= -1.7580993408473766, fixedPointMean=0.0, fixedPointVar=1.0,
                 noise_shape=None, seed=None, name=None, training=False):
    """Dropout to a value with rescaling."""

    def dropout_selu_impl(x, rate, alpha, noise_shape, seed, name):
        keep_prob = 1.0 - rate
        x = ops.convert_to_tensor(x, name="x")
        if isinstance(keep_prob, numbers.Real) and not 0 < keep_prob <= 1:
            raise ValueError("keep_prob must be a scalar tensor or a float in the "
                                             "range (0, 1], got %g" % keep_prob)
        keep_prob = ops.convert_to_tensor(keep_prob, dtype=x.dtype, name="keep_prob")
        keep_prob.get_shape().assert_is_compatible_with(tensor_shape.scalar())

        alpha = ops.convert_to_tensor(alpha, dtype=x.dtype, name="alpha")
        alpha.get_shape().assert_is_compatible_with(tensor_shape.scalar())

        if tensor_util.constant_value(keep_prob) == 1:
            return x

        noise_shape = noise_shape if noise_shape is not None else array_ops.shape(x)
        random_tensor = keep_prob
        random_tensor += random_ops.random_uniform(noise_shape, seed=seed, dtype=x.dtype)
        binary_tensor = math_ops.floor(random_tensor)
        ret = x * binary_tensor + alpha * (1-binary_tensor)

        a = math_ops.sqrt(fixedPointVar / (keep_prob *((1-keep_prob) * math_ops.pow(alpha-fixedPointMean,2) + fixedPointVar)))

        b = fixedPointMean - a * (keep_prob * fixedPointMean + (1 - keep_prob) * alpha)
        ret = a * ret + b
        ret.set_shape(x.get_shape())
        return ret

    with ops.name_scope(name, "dropout", [x]) as name:
        return utils.smart_cond(training,
            lambda: dropout_selu_impl(x, rate, alpha, noise_shape, seed, name),
            lambda: array_ops.identity(x))

#-----------------------------------------------#
# build a 3-layer dense network with SELU activation and alpha-dropout
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

w1 = tf.constant(np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=np.sqrt(1.0/15.0), size = [15, 30]))
b1 = tf.constant(np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=0.5, size = [30]))

x1 = tf.constant(np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size = [200, 15]))
y1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x1, w1), b1)
y1_selu = selu(y1)
y1_selu_dropout = dropout_selu(y1_selu, 0.05, training=True)

w2 = tf.constant(np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=np.sqrt(1.0/30.0), size = [30, 30]))
b2 = tf.constant(np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=0.5, size = [30]))

x2 = y1_selu_dropout 
y2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x2, w2), b2)
y2_selu = selu(y2)
y2_selu_dropout = dropout_selu(y2_selu, 0.05, training=True)


w3 = tf.constant(np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=np.sqrt(1.0/30.0), size = [30, 8]))
b3 = tf.constant(np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=0.5, size = [8]))

x3 = y2_selu_dropout 
y3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x3, w3), b3)
y3_selu = selu(y3)
y3_selu_dropout = dropout_selu(y3_selu, 0.05, training=True)


#-------------------------#
# evaluate the network
x1_v, y1_selu_dropout_v, \
x2_v, y2_selu_dropout_v, \
x3_v, y3_selu_dropout_v, \
 = sess.run([x1, y1_selu_dropout, x2, y2_selu_dropout, x3, y3_selu_dropout]) 

#-------------------------#
# print each layer's mean and standard deviation (1st line: input; 2nd line: output)
print("Layer 1")
print(np.mean(x1_v), np.std(x1_v))
print(np.mean(y1_selu_dropout_v), np.std(y1_selu_dropout_v))
print("Layer 2")
print(np.mean(x2_v), np.std(x2_v))
print(np.mean(y2_selu_dropout_v), np.std(y2_selu_dropout_v))
print("Layer 3")
print(np.mean(x3_v), np.std(x3_v))
print(np.mean(y3_selu_dropout_v), np.std(y3_selu_dropout_v))
```

Here is one possible output. Over 3 layers, the mean and standard deviation are still close to 0 and 1, respectively.

```
Layer 1
-0.0101213033749 1.01375071842
0.0106228883975 1.09375593322
Layer 2
0.0106228883975 1.09375593322
-0.027910206754 1.12216643393
Layer 3
-0.027910206754 1.12216643393
-0.131790078631 1.09698413493
```